# QML - TableViewColumn quick control 1 alert "Model size of -2 less than 0"

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I am working on qt quick control and I am having a problem with TableViewColumn in QtQuick.Controls 1.4. I wanna create a TabView have 2 tabs like below image
[image]

The first, I created a TabBar with this code

```
    TabBar {
    id: tabBarScriptLinker
    anchors.top: tbvDevices.bottom
    anchors.topMargin: 10
    anchors.left: tbvDevices.left
    anchors.right: tbvDevices.right
    position: TabBar.Header

    TabButton{
        height: parent.height
        background: Rectangle{
            color: tabBarScriptLinker.currentIndex == 0 ? qsTr("#5661f7") : qsTr("#ddd9f9")
        }

        contentItem: Text{
            text: "Scence"
            font.pixelSize: 12
            font.bold: true
            color: tabBarScriptLinker.currentIndex == 0 ? qsTr("white") : qsTr("black")
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        }
    }
    TabButton{
        height: parent.height
        background: Rectangle{
            color: tabBarScriptLinker.currentIndex == 1 ? qsTr("#5661f7") : qsTr("#ddd9f9")
        }
        contentItem: Text{
            text: "Linker"
            font.pixelSize: 12
            font.bold: true
            color: tabBarScriptLinker.currentIndex == 1 ? qsTr("white") : qsTr("black")
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        }
    }
}
```

After that, I continued creating a StackLayout and a table view will be follow below the TabBar

```
StackLayout{
    anchors.top: tabBarScriptLinker.bottom
    anchors.left: tabBarScriptLinker.left
    anchors.right: tabBarScriptLinker.right
    anchors.bottom: rLayoutScLiControl.top
    anchors.bottomMargin: 10
    currentIndex: tabBarScriptLinker.currentIndex
    Item {
        id: sceneTab
        Layout.fillWidth: parent.width
        Layout.fillHeight: parent.height
        QtC1.TableView{
            id: tbvScences
            anchors.fill: parent
            ListModel{
                id: lstScences
                ListElement{
                    num: 1
                    name: qsTr("on all")
                }
                ListElement{
                    num: 1
                    name: qsTr("off all")
                }
            }

            /* Create columns */
            QtC1.TableViewColumn{
                id: tbvScences_num
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                role: qsTr("num")
                title: qsTr("Num")
                width: 40
            }
            QtC1.TableViewColumn{
                id: tbvScences_Name
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                role: qsTr("name")
                title: qsTr("Name")
                width: 60
            }
            model: lstScences
        }
    }
    Item {
        id: linkerTab
        Layout.fillWidth: parent.width
        Layout.fillHeight: parent.height
        QtC1.TableView{
            id: tbvLinkers
            anchors.fill: parent
            ListModel{
                id: lstLinkers
                ListElement{
                    label: qsTr("Tang 4518")
                    MAC: qsTr("65-46-AF-4C-6B-91")
                }
                ListElement{
                    label: qsTr("Tang 56")
                    MAC: qsTr("25-02-AF-C8-6B-21")
                }
            }

            /* Create columns */
            QtC1.TableViewColumn{
                id: tbvLinkers_Label
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignLeft
                role: qsTr("label")
                title: qsTr("Label")
                width: 100
            }
            QtC1.TableViewColumn{
                id: tbvLinkers_MAC
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignLeft
                role: qsTr("MAC")
                title: qsTr("MAC")
                width: 120
            }
            model: lstLinkers
        }
    }
}
```

It worked fine same my expectation but some strange log appeared

"Model size of -2 is less than 0" in application out tab
And when I click on "Linker" tab a little changing to
"Model size of -3 is less than 0" in application out tab

I think my application has a problem, can anyone give me the reason? Is this issue worth considering?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce the behavior with a simple example, and it seems to happen whenever the size of the window is smaller than the size of the tableView

Edit: could be this: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-72543